# android audio - generating a simple customizable bell/gong sound

Tags: android, audio

I am writing a countdown timer for android right now and I want to give the user the possibility to customize the sound used for it. Rather than offering a set of fixed sounds i would prefer to give the user some settings in the hand with which the sound can be customized (and the app generates the sound based on the user settings). I would like a basic bell/gong type of sound, nothing fancy.

I found libraries like [jass](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kvdoel/jass/) which offer this kind of audio generation yet i havent found something which i can use for android.

It would be great if somebody could give me some ideas in which direction to look.

Comment: I don't know if jsyn is android compatible.

Comment: bell/gong sounds are often made using FM synthesis or ring modulation.

Comment: thx Bjorn, looks interesting yet I cant find any reference that it can be used with android - I assume it uses the standard Java Sound API which is not available in android. Also my project is not open source so i cant use it for that reason. Anyway, thanks once more for the hint.